# Django redirect after search using a queryset

Tags: python, html, django

When I click search on the homepage, I want it to take that query set e.g (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=car`) and then use the same url, but in the search view. I have tried searching around but couldn't find anything that was working.

Views:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = Post
    # queryset = Post.objects.filter(live=True)
    template_name = "public/index.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(live=True)
       query = self.request.GET.get("q")
       if query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=query)
       return redirect(reverse('search-view'), queryset)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['queryset'] = self.get_queryset()
        context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index-view"),

    path('post/create/', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name="post-create"),
    path('post/<slug>/update/', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),
    path('post/<slug>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),

    path('category/', views.CategoryView.as_view(), name="category"),
    path('category/<int:pk>/', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name="category-detail"),

    path('search/', views.SearchListView.as_view(), name="search-view")
]
```

I have tried doing it using a redirect and reverse but it is not working at all, it is actually giving me an error for using slice on a forloop that is using queryset. `'slice' object has no attribute 'lower'`

I have 2 templates/views. When I click search on the homepage, I want it to carry on over to the search view and then run the search query on there.

Thanks.

Comment: "*I have tried doing it using a redirect and reverse but it is not working at all.*"
Can you specify **what** is not working?

Comment: @Johan Ah yes sorry my fault. So when I load the IndexView, it gives me an error  about using slice. Now I am using slice in a forloop on the IndexView template.

Comment: No worries. I believe you need to use a named parameter in the `redirect` function, basically like `redirect(reverse('search-view'), queryset=queryset)` and then handle the argument in the `SearchListView`

Comment: Or possibly `redirect(reverse('search-view'), args=(queryset))`

Comment: I have added queryset=queryset but not sure how to handle the argument in the SearchListView, sorry I am fairly new to Django.

Comment: No problem, we've all been new to Django at one point :) If you include your `SearchListView` class it'd be easier to show how it will need to handle the request, since it's the view that we will redirect to.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing up the logic a bit on where to do the actual query. You should't do the actual query search in the `IndexView` that is meant for the `SearchListView`.

From the information that's available right now (without the `SearchListView`) I'd say you could do a redirect and pass the parameter onto the query url and let the view in `SearchListView` decide what to do with the information:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(live=True)
    query = self.request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        # Fetch the url for the search-view
        base_url = reverse('search-view')
        # Make the search query url encoded
        query_string =  urlencode({'q': query})
        # Tie it together with the url
        url = '{}?{}'.format(base_url, query_string)
        # Fire away
        return redirect(url)
    return redirect(reverse('search-view'), queryset)
```

**Source**:
Some code taken from [The Ultimate Guide to Django Redirects](https://realpython.com/django-redirects/#passing-parameters-with-redirects) by [Daniel Hepper](https://realpython.com/django-redirects/#author)

Comment: I get **AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'filter'**